# Upload Multiple Files - random error

Tags: file-upload, error

In the Upload Document dialog box, when I click Upload Multiple Files..., I get Microsoft .NET Framework error dialog box. When I click on Details button, it gives the following error message:

> System.ArgumentException: Value does
>   not fall within the expected range.
>   at
>   mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById(String
>   v)    at
>   STSUpld.UploadCtl.ToggleHtmlButtons(Boolean
>   enabledone)    at
>   STSUpld.UploadCtl.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.OnCreateControl()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean
>   fIgnoreVisible)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
>   at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.UserControl.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ActiveXImpl.System.Windows.Forms.IWindowTarget.OnMessage(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message&
>   m)    at
>   System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr
>   hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr
>   lparam)

```
    
    ************** Loaded Assemblies ************** mscorlib
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3603 (GDR.050727-3600)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
    ---------------------------------------- stsupld
        Assembly Version: 14.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 14.0.4514.1004
        CodeBase: file:///C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~4/Office14/STSUPLD.DLL
    ---------------------------------------- System.Windows.Forms
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
    ---------------------------------------- System
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
    ---------------------------------------- System.Drawing
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
    ---------------------------------------- Accessibility
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_MSIL/Accessibility/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Accessibility.dll
    ---------------------------------------- stsupld.intl
        Assembly Version: 14.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 14.0.4514.1004
        CodeBase: file:///c:/progra~1/micros~4/office14/1033/stsupld.intl.dll
    ---------------------------------------- Microsoft.mshtml
        Assembly Version: 7.0.3300.0
        Win32 Version: 7.0.3300.0
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC/Microsoft.mshtml/7.0.3300.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/Microsoft.mshtml.dll
    ---------------------------------------- CustomMarshalers
        Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
        Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.3053 (netfxsp.050727-3000)
        CodeBase: file:///C:/WINDOWS/assembly/GAC_32/CustomMarshalers/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/CustomMarshalers.dll
    ----------------------------------------
```

This is happening randomly and I am unable to reproduce the error always.

I am using Windows XP SP3 - Office 2010 Beta and accessing SharePoint 2010 site using IE 8.

Anyone faced this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried upgrading to .NET Framework 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/NullReferenceException-when-uploading-multiple-files-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx

It might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are any documents uploading? and if so, do any of your documents have special characters in the names? I had an issue with multiple docs if they had special characters in the names